# WSS4J complains "No Subject DN Certificate Constraints were defined. This could be a security issue" using Axis2 Rampart

Tags: wso2, cxf, apache-axis, rampart, wss4j

We see the following warning message using Rampart-1.6.2 and wss4j-1.6.14. We wonder if anyone can advise how to set the cert subject DN constraint in Rampart. We found a way for Apache CXF though: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html

```
No Subject DN Certificate Constraints were defined. This could be a security issue
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DN Cert Constraints can be configured in WSS4J by specifying a Configuration tags.
  check on http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config

Comment: Thank you Dakashika for your advice but I am not familiar how to pass the tag config to WSS4J through a side channel instead of going through Rampart. As you may already know, Rampart appears not to do this for us: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/rampartconfig-guide.html

Comment: For now, we will simply suppress the warning by setting in log4j log4j.logger.org.apache.ws.security.validate.SignatureTrustValidator=ERROR